# Lenovo IdeaPad 1 11ADA05: How can I access the eMMC?

Tags: kernel, lenovo, ideapad, emmc

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 1 11ADA05 on which I would like to install Kubuntu. I can boot into the live session just fine, everything works (graphics, WiFi, Sound...). However the installer doesn't see the eMMC this machine has. I've played around with different UEFI settings, secureboot on and off, the thing even has a "setup mode" in the UEFI, but nothing seems to make a difference. A generic non-machine specific Windows10 installation USB stick sees the eMMC and installs fine, so I guess it can't be too exotic?!? Here's a hw-probe out of the live session, I can't even tell if the kernel find's the SD-controller to which the eMMC is supposedly connected, can anyone have a look?
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=5885335d44

It seems to run Kubuntu very nicely and would be a pity if I couldn't install it. The UEFI lists the eMMC as Ramaxel 64GB and furthermore "hard disk" as not installed. I opened the case and found mounting holes to mount an M.2 (I guess), there are also the soldering pads on the PCB but the M.2 socket is not soldered on, so that would only be a last resort solution, if the eMMC can't be used at all...

Looking forward to any hints!

Comment: Try this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627706/4212

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Ubuntu mainline Kernel 5.13.0-051300rc1-generic the eMMC is now detected.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your laptop is too new for Linux 5.8. Try any Linux distro with latest Linux (5.10), e.g. Guix: https://guix.gnu.org/en/download/latest/

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your hint! I booted Guix, but it stops here and just sits there indefinitely: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-10e522-1609155258.jpg.html    Then I booted Kubuntu from the live USB-stick, installed it on a second USB-stick, booted from that and updated to the 5.10 mainline kernel. Boots fine, but still does not see the eMMC. So I am out of luck it looks like? I will wait for the next kernel versions and hope for the best...

Answer (score 1):

I have the 14ADA05 and no version of Linux will detect the eMMC drive, I have tried Lubuntu, Arch & Mint.  I have used a Samsung FIT 32GB USB3 (using a 32GB SHXC card with install binaries) to install Lubuntu and it rocks.  However, I believe the eMMC controller is not yet supported in the Linux community but I don't know how to identify an unknown device.  dmesg shows one "AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter" and "pci 0000:00:00.2 can't derive routing for PCI INT A", but there are more messages that could point to the type of hardware but I don't know what to look for.  https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3aca8223d6